# Force HTTPS causing 404 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess to force redirection to https://www.domain.com using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The above result in a page with encrypted output: [image]
Is this a problem on my htaccess or, a server problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare doesn't use 443 port so, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

Comment: Indeed, I've leaned that HTTPS does not really required the port to be set to 443 (which was my case). Specifying port 80 did the trick. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

A server problem would be noted with a 5xx error. Check your logs and   try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]  
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www\." [NC]  
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Almost right - the Rewrite Rule should point to https, not http.